# Is it possible to get localized file in Windows Store 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am trying to get localized file for current language.

I put file to `Resources/en-US/layer_items.json` and set BuildAction to Content and trying to find him with this code

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Resources/layer_items.json");
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
        string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

but i get FileNotFound Exception.

How can i get localized file in Windows Store 8.1 app?

Comment: What you're doing sounds right and your code works for me on en-us with the Resources/en-US/layer_items.json file. I'd check the Appx folder to make sure that layer_items.json is in the package where you expect it and confirm that the app is running in en-us.

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT i forget to note one important thing: file and ReadTextAsync are in PCL library referenced in app

Comment: What do you mean the file is in the PCL library? The ms-appx:/// protocol will reference from the root of the appx package even if it's called from a library hosted deeper in the package.

Comment: File added as Content to PCL library, ReadTextAsync belong to class method inside this library. This class created and called in the main app => file not found. Also, i don't see the file in Appx folder